# SQL server Run job with parameter of table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, jobs, auto

I want to run Sql server job store procedure with parameter from table.
Table Parameter is inserted from web.
Table with  column ID (auto identify), column Username.
I have a store procedure run with this parameter. When store procedure run 1 parameter, it delete that parameter and run next parameter.
Code my job is:

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(50);
select @name = username from [dbo].[Job_parameter];
EXEC [dbo].[SP_A] @username= @name;
```

Exam: when table has 1 row username, code run ok but long time. but when table have > 1 row, job run fail. I run job  with this code is fail
Can you help me?
and I can run job auto when table parameter have data??
Exam code here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a75b00a3d37291ad682c6732109dc28b

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you're asking here. You say your code fails, however, you provide no error, so how do you know it's failing? If you need to run a Procedure for multiple rows then you would likely need to create a table type parameter and pass that to the Procedure instead.

Comment: @ Larnu: when i run procedure for multiple rows, this query  no show error messages, it take long time and dont finish query. Can you help me how to run a Procedure for multiple rows from job?

Comment: What do you mean "from job", an agent job? SQL run in an agent job is no different to other SQL. Without the DDL of your Procedure, explaining how to alter this would be impossible. Certainly, however, `select @name = username from [dbo].[Job_parameter];` isn't going to work as you expect if `Job_parameter` contains 2+ rows.

Comment: @ Larnu: i don't good about sql server, i search google, so query not good. Can you help me solve this problem? i want run 1 job, this job run query to start store procedure for multiple rows

Comment: Again, *"Without the DDL of your Procedure, explaining how to alter this would be impossible."* If you can't/won't give us the DDL, then I like I suggested, use a table type parameter.

Comment: When there's more than 1 row in the Job_parameter table this code will fail due to the variable assignment of @name.  You cannot assign a value from more than 1 row to a scalar variable.

Comment: @Larnu: Exam code here:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a75b00a3d37291ad682c6732109dc28b